# Unexpiring an expired SQL Server Login password (Password cannot be changed)

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have a SQL server Login which password has recently expired. Unfortunately this password is necessary as we use it across Dev Machines for application testing purposes.

I CAN'T change this password, but I need to unexpire it.

The error I am getting is : 
Error 28000 Login failed for user 'Username'. Reason: The password of the account has expired.

I am using SQL Server 2014.
The 'Enforce Password Policy' box is not ticked.

Comment: Why don't you just drop and re-create the login, and make sure this time `CHECK_POLICY = OFF`.

Comment: I've tried that, I even dropped the table and login and recreated from a colleagues back up who's was working fine and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: "Recreated from a colleagues back up" - why? `DROP LOGIN foo; CREATE LOGIN foo WITH PASSWORD = N'whatever', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;` - done

Comment: That's what I did, didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Log in as a system administrator.  Change the password to something else.  Make sure enforce password policy is off and then change the password back to the original password.

Comment: Weird I tried this before recreating the database and it didn't work, after I restored the database from a backup and tried this it worked, Weird voodoo man.

Answer (score 56):

Right click 'Username' and go to Properties

You can find 'Enforce password expiration' on login properties window, which needs to be unchecked.

[image]

Comment: This was the perfect answer! I could manage to unchecked the "Enforce password expiration" checkbox and my application started working immediately.

Comment: I had to restart the machine also to get this to work.

Comment: Agree with @AaBa. Worked for me after just unchecking it.

Comment: MS SQL 2017: After I checked checkbox I got error: The CHECK_POLICY and CHECK_EXPIRATION options cannot be turned OFF when MUST_CHANGE is ON. --> I had to remove login and create new one without "enforce password policy"

Answer (score 0):

I connected in SQL studio using the account and was required to input the new password. 
I typed the same password and it worked then.  (Did not want to change the password because other applications may still use it. )