# SQL Server 2016 Express loses the sa password

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Express and it is used by a client/server application. I use the SQL Server autentication `sa` + password.

Every 4/5 days the client applications fails to logon to the DB. In this scenario if I try to connect to the engine via SQL Server Management Studio I get an error.

So I logon via Windows authentication, then I change the `sa` password [retyping the old one] and for a few days it work fine, then the problem occurs again.

- At the beginning the password was very week so I changed with a stronger one. It uses 7 lowercase chars + 3 numbers
- In the "property form" for `sa` user every checks in off

Any ideas about the issue?

Thanks to everyone [and sorry for my bad English]

Comment: Did you try on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577442/unexpiring-an-expired-sql-server-login-password-password-cannot-be-changed

Comment: What is the error when you try to login as `sa` and fail - please post the error when you login via SSMS as `sa` and it fails.